# Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: Proxy Authentication Required

Tags: docker, proxy, redhat

Good morning I am starting with a docker on a RED HAT 8 server, but I am having problems to make the docker run hello work, I get the following error:

```
[root@srvdevrma1 ~]# docker run hello-world
Unable to find image ‘hello-world:latest’ locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: Proxy Authentication Required.
See ‘docker run --help’.
```

Same when I’m going to login

```
[root@srvdevrma1 ~]# docker login
Login with your Docker ID to push and pull images from Docker Hub. If you don’t have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com to create one.
Username: cesarjv
Password:
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: Proxy Authentication Required
[root@srvdevrma1 ~]#

Configure my proxy:

[root@srvdevrma1 ~]# echo $http_proxy
http://E10697:xxxxxx++@10.162.64.36:8080/

[root@srvdevrma1 ~]# echo $https_proxy
http://E10697:xxxxxx++@10.162.64.36:8080/

[root@srvdevrma1 ~]# cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy.conf
Acquire::http::Proxy “http://E10697:xxxxxx++@10.162.64.36:8080//”;
Acquire::https::Proxy “http://E10697:xxxxxx++@10.162.64.36:8080//”;

[root@srvdevrma1 ~]# cat /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf
[Service]
Environment=“HTTP_PROXY=10.162.64.36:8080”
Environment=“HTTPS_PROXY=10.162.64.36:8080”
Environment=“NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1”
```

then run

```
systemctl daemon-reload

systemctl restart docker
```

Where can I be failing?

Comment: i presume you reloaded your daemon after the proxy configurations

Comment: Of course, I run: systemctl daemon-reload systemctl restart docker

Comment: Why is your system proxy config and docker proxy config different? where are the auth details in your docker proxy?

Comment: So it appears in the tutorials that I have seen on the internet, could you place the answer of how it should go?

Comment: Its the same how it shows when you do echo $http_proxy `http://E10697:xxxxxx++@10.162.64.36:8080`

Comment: Should it go that way as you tell me? : Environment = http: // E10697: xxxxxx++@10.162.64.36: 8080

Comment: Environment=“HTTP_PROXY=E10697:xxxxxx++@10.162.64.36:8080”
Environment=“HTTPS_PROXY=E10697:xxxxxx++@10.162.64.36:8080”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment=“HTTP_PROXY=E10697:xxxxxx++@10.162.64.36:8080”
Environment=“HTTPS_PROXY=E10697:xxxxxx++@10.162.64.36:8080”

This must resolve

Answer (score 0):

There's no docker in RHEL 8. RH built docker-compatible tools (Podman, Buildah) that don't require a daemon.

Use

## yum install -y podman

## alias docker=podman

See these docs/pages:
[Intro to RHEL 8 container tools](https://developers.redhat.com/topics/containers/)

[Containers without Daemons](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/11/20/buildah-podman-containers-without-daemons/)

Also, see this [intro to RHEL 8 page](https://developers.redhat.com/rhel8/).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

```
$ docker pull cockroach-db
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": Proxy 
Authentication Required
```

There is possibly > 1 spot that docker looks at for this.

```
~/.docker/config.json
/etc/docker/daemon.conf
/etc/default/docker
```

My password was old in these files.
I updated them and it still wasnt working.

Turns out I needed to re-start the service

```
$ sudo service docker start
```

Once I did this, a git pull worked.